# Ruby group_by method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app I have single and recurring events.

```
Event(..., starts_at: datetime, is_recurrent: boolean, period: datetime, ends_at: datetime)
```

If event is single I am using `starts_at` field to determine when it occurs. For the recurring events I am using `ends_at` and `period` fields as well.

For the just single events I can simply write something like this:

**controller:**

```
@events_by_date = @events.group_by{ |event| event.starts_at.to_date }
```

**view:**

```
<%= render :partial => "event", :collection => @events_by_date[date] %>
```

But I have no idea how I can implement this for example for daily events. 
Now all events (both, single and recurring) are shown only when they start(because I'm using `group_by{ |event| event.starts_at.to_date }`). I want to make so if event starts at 24 of March and ends at 30 of March, this event must be shown on the each day cell before 31 of March. 
Could I use **group_by** method for these purposes?

[image]

Comment: Can you give some more details about what you want to do?  it's not clear (to me at least) what you mean by `how I can implement this for example for daily events.`

Comment: Oh, wait: do you mean you want to group the recurrent events by the time that they start?  How about `@events_by_time = @events.group_by{ |event| event.starts_at.strftime("%H-%M) }`

Comment: @MaxWilliams thank you for your reply. Sorry for confusing. I added picture. Hope It helps you to understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do it in single `group_by`

```
@events_by_date = @events.reject{|event| event.is_recurrent}.group_by{ |event| event.starts_at.to_date }
@events.select{|event| event.is_recurrent}.map do |event|
  (event.starts_at..event.ends_at).each do |time|
    @events_by_date[time.to_date] ||= []; 
    @events_by_date[time.to_date] << event
  end
end
```